# outputting dictionary values to text file: uncoupling lists and strings

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary called `shared_double_lists` which is made of 6 keys called `[(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (0, 3), (0, 2)]`. The values for all the keys are lists.

I am trying to output the values for key `(0, 1)` to a file. Here is my code:

```
output = open('test_output.txt', 'w')
counter = 0
for locus in shared_double_lists[(0, 1)]:
    for value in locus:
        output.write(str(shared_double_lists[(0, 1)][counter]))
        output.write ("\t")
    output.write ("\n")
    counter +=1
output.close()
```

This almost works, the output looks like this:

```
['ACmerged_contig_10464', '1259', '.', 'G', 'C', '11.7172', '.', 'DP=1;SGB=-0.379885;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,0,1,0;MQ=41', 'GT:PL', '1/1:41,3,0']
['ACmerged_contig_10464', '1260', '.', 'A', 'T', '11.7172', '.', 'DP=1;SGB=-0.379885;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,0,1,0;MQ=41', 'GT:PL', '1/1:41,3,0']
```

Whereas I want it to look like this:

```
ACmerged_contig_10464 1259 . G C 11.7172 . DP=1;SGB=-0.379885;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,0,1,0;MQ=41 GT:PL 1/1:41,3,0
ACmerged_contig_10464 1260 . A T 11.7172 . DP=1;SGB=-0.379885;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,0,1,0;MQ=41 GT:PL 1/1:41,3,0
```

i.e. not have the lines of text in list format in the file, but have each item of each list separated by a tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply join lists to a string: [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
my_string = '\t'.join(my_list)
```

\t should join them with a tab, but you can use what you want there.

In this example:

```
output.write('\t'.join(shared_double_lists[(0, 1)][counter]))
```

Comment: can you explain how to use this in the context of my question? i.e. to actually get the lists in the dictionary to write out normally without list formatting?